# Unable to use Swift object's variables in Objective-C View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am facing a problem accessing variables of a class written in Swift from a view controller written in Objective-C.

I have already created the Bridging Header and I have successfully sent the Swift object from a view controller written in Swift to another one written in Objective-C. The problem is that I want to access the variables of the object but I get the following error: **Property 'variableName' cannot be found in forward class object 'className'**.

Here is the class which I am trying to access its variables:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

@objcMembers
class SwiftObject: NSObject {

    // MARK: - Variables
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var contact: SwiftSubObjectA
    var location: SwiftSubObjectB
    var categories: [SwiftSubObjectC] = []

    // MARK: - Initializers
    init(withJSON json: JSON) {
        self.id = json["id"].stringValue
        self.name = json["name"].stringValue
        self.contact = SwiftSubObjectA(withJSON: json["contact"])
        self.location = SwiftSubObjectB(withJSON: json["location"])

        for categoryJSON in json["categories"].arrayValue {
            categories.append(SwiftSubObjectC(withJSON: categoryJSON))
        }

    }

}
```

And this is how I am sending the object into the Objective-C view controller

```
class SwiftViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let objectiveVC.object = segue.destination as? ObjectiveViewController else { return }
        guard let object = sender as? SwiftObject else { return }
        objectiveVC.object = object
    }

}
```

Finally, this is the Objective-C view controller .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SwiftObject;

@interface ObjectiveViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) SwiftObject * _Nonnull object;

@end
```

and the .m file:

```
#import "ObjectiveViewController.h"
#import "Project-Bridging-Header.h"

@interface ObjectiveViewController ()

@end

@implementation ObjectiveViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.object.name);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@end
```

The problem is that the self.object does not have any available variables to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access Swift object in your Objective-C Class you need to import `Project-Swift.h`in your .m file as shown below

```
#import "Project-Swift.h"

@implementation ObjectiveViewController 

//... other code

@end
```

Project is the name of the project. Add the import statement in your `ObjectiveViewController.m` file

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you!! I had applied it but I deleted it by mistake.

Comment: @pv169 : Am glad you found the solution :)